# Hide component name from urls in joomla

Tags: joomla

I need to hide component name in joomla urls.
I have also applied configuration for SEO urls in administrator.
But still it is displaying component name in urls
So please suggest me appropriate  solution for hiding component name in urls

Comment: Create a menu item for the pages you want and link to those menu items and you typically get the menu item's name in the url instead of the component name. Gives you control.

Comment: You can create menu links for required menu items and use alias of those.

Comment: Add a menu link for each top level category (or lower if you want). That way you'll never get component though you will always get the category structure instead.

Answer (score 7):

You need to create a menu item (or tree of items) to the component. The `alias` you give the menu will appear in the URL.